# search for multiple substrings from a string in python

Tags: python, search

I have a list of strings like

```
Env = [
    'APAC_CHINA_UAT_D2','APAC_CHINA_UAT_D5','APAC_INDIA_Q1_UAT',
    'AMER_US_T8_UAT','AMER_US_W2_UAT','AMER_US_Q9_PROD',
    'EMEA_UK_K8_UAT','EMEA_DUBAI_QA_UAT']
```

I'm giving user a text area where user can write any substring matching the Env's in the above list

User can enter substring separated by space:- APAC CHINA

so i have to display a list containing APAC and CHINA

```
List =['APAC_CHINA_UAT_D2','APAC_CHINA_UAT_D5']
```

If user enters:- AMER UAT

Then the list would be

```
List = ['AMER_US_T8_UAT','AMER_US_W2_UAT']
```

Similarly for: - AMER US T8 UAT

i'd get only one list `List = ['AMER_US_T8_UAT']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input:

```py
Env = [
    'APAC_CHINA_UAT_D2',
    'APAC_CHINA_UAT_D5',
    'APAC_INDIA_Q1_UAT',
    'AMER_US_T8_UAT',
    'AMER_US_W2_UAT',
    'AMER_US_Q9_PROD',
    'EMEA_UK_K8_UAT',
    'EMEA_DUBAI_QA_UAT']
search = 'APAC CHINA'
```

Detailed, lengthy version:

```py
List = []                          # empty result list
for e in Env:                      # for each item e of Env
    contains = True                # initially assume that e contains each search string
    for s in search.split():       # for each word s in the search string (split at whitespace)
        if not s in e.split('_'):  # if e (split at '_') does not contain search string s
            contains = False       # e does *not* contain each search string
    if contains:                   # if e contains all search strings
        List.append(e)             # append e to result list
print List                         # print result list
```

One-liner:

```py
print [e for e in Env if all([s in e.split('_') for s in search.split()])]
```

Output:

```
['APAC_CHINA_UAT_D2', 'APAC_CHINA_UAT_D5']
```